# Update numbers from a list of list with names

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list made like this:

```
matrix=[[3,1,2],[4],[2,1],[2]]
```

Also i have a vector with names and their indices:

```
names=["Jack","Michael","Gwen","Paul"]
indices=[0,1,2,3]
```

Is there a way to update indices of the matrix with the names?
I know how to do it in O(n^2), are there any better way do to it?

P.S. I edit the question because I forgot a possible important information: matrix and names have the same length.

Comment: do you mean that you want to replace `[3,1], [1]` with `['Gwen', 'Jack'], ['Jack']`?

Comment: Yes that's the idea

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the easy way with two for as the first answer, but it's O(n^2) and it's quite slow in the real list I have

Comment: @DuccioBorchi Two for loops does not imply O(n^2).

Comment: Yeah you're right, but it is possible to not do the double loop?

Comment: You can try using Numpy. It's way faster than core Python (they've optimised the code a lot in the backend with parallelism which you can't really do yourself in core Python)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `indices` just enumerates the list positions in `names` and adds 1. It's not really needed.

```
>>> [[names[i - 1] for i in sublist] for sublist in matrix]
[['Gwen', 'Jack', 'Michael'], ['Paul'], ['Michael', 'Jack']]
```

Comment: Do you have some references on this? Doing nested for loops with list comprehension should still be `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @ccl Two for loops does not imply O(n^2). There is one constant time operation for each number in `matrix`. Let's assume `matrix` had 10 sublists of 5 elements each. Then the nested list comprehension would perform 10*5 = 50 = n constant time operations.

Comment: I prefer not to use nested loops because my real matrix has more than 2000 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Numpy package, which vectorises and parallelises its operations (should be faster than `O(n^2)`)

```
matrix=[[3,1,2],[4],[2,1]]
matrix = np.array([np.array(i) for i in matrix])
names= np.array(["Jack","Michael","Gwen","Paul"])
names1 = [names[i-1].tolist() for i in matrix]
print(names1)
```

Which returns `[['Gwen', 'Jack', 'Michael'], ['Paul'], ['Michael', 'Jack']]`.

Answer (score 0):

you can put those two `lists` into a single `dictionary`. And nested list comprehension will do the rest. I hope this will work for you,

```
dic = dict(zip(indices,names))
l = [[dic[q] for q in sub] for sub in matrix]
```

This returns,

```
[['Gwen', 'Jack', 'Michael'], ['Paul'], ['Michael', 'Jack']]
```